# Multiline JSON string without JShint warning

Tags: javascript, json, string, jshint

To create multiline strings in json I use the following:

```
"defaultTemplates" : {
             "vcs.vcm.layer.Vector" : {
                 "<html><head></head><body>",
                 "<div style='position:fixed;>",
                 "...."
```

However, JShint doesnt like this very much and reports:
"Expected colon instead saw comma", which normally makes sense, but not for a multiline string..

Anybody knows how to either create multiline strings differently so that jshint is ok, or else.. how to disable this warning in jshint ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `"<html><head></head><body>",
                 "<div style='position:fixed;>",`? That's invalid JSON

Comment: Looks like a website template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the multiline string as an array in JSON.

```
"template": {
  "lines": [
    "line1",
    "line2",
    "line3"
  ]
}
```

Then, use JavaScript code to join the lines with newline characters.

```
var multilineString = template.lines.join("\n");
```